# "List" property breaks retrieval of UnsubEvent

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

[The documentation on UnsubEvents states](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/unsubevent/) I should be able to add a "List" property to learn from which list a user unsubscribed. However, when I use the List parameter, I receive "Error: The Request Property(s) List do not match with the fields of UnsubEvent retrieve".

This appears to be an issue with the ExactTarget API. It would be great to have this corrected because currently I can only get unsubscribes without knowing which lists were effected. Also, since no results are returned when using the "List" property, existing implementations for other customers may be failing to retrieve unsubscribes.

Below, I have documented both a failed request with the "List" parameter, and a succeeding request where the only alteration is the removal of the "List" parameter.

Thank you for looking into this!

---

Request URL: https://webservice.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx (correct for my instance)

**A REQUEST WITH THE LIST PROPERTY**

**Request Body**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Header>
    <Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <UsernameToken>
        <Username>***</Username>
       <Password>***</Password>
      </UsernameToken>
    </Security>
  </Header>
  <Body>
    <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
      <RetrieveRequest>
        <ObjectType>UnsubEvent</ObjectType>
        <Properties>SendID</Properties>
        <Properties>EventDate</Properties>
        <Properties>SubscriberKey</Properties>
        <Properties>List</Properties>
        <Filter xsi:type="ComplexFilterPart">
          <LeftOperand xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
            <Property>EventDate</Property>
            <SimpleOperator>greaterThanOrEqual</SimpleOperator>
            <DateValue>2014-11-24T21:42:03</DateValue>
          </LeftOperand>
          <LogicalOperator>AND</LogicalOperator>
          <RightOperand xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
            <Property>EventDate</Property>
            <SimpleOperator>lessThan</SimpleOperator>
            <DateValue>2014-11-24T22:42:03</DateValue>
          </RightOperand>
        </Filter>
      </RetrieveRequest>
    </RetrieveRequestMsg>
  </Body>
</Envelope>
```

**Response Information**

```
HTTP status: 200 OK
<OverallStatus>Error: The Request Property(s) List do not match with the fields of UnsubEvent retrieve</OverallStatus>
<RequestID>d2838a58-e98d-44f2-9e92-2ef358f5b853</RequestID>
```

**A REQUEST WITHOUT THE LIST PROPERTY**

**Request Body**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Header>
    <Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <UsernameToken>
        <Username>***</Username>
        <Password>***</Password>
      </UsernameToken>
    </Security>
  </Header>
  <Body>
    <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
      <RetrieveRequest>
        <ObjectType>UnsubEvent</ObjectType>
        <Properties>SendID</Properties>
        <Properties>EventDate</Properties>
        <Properties>SubscriberKey</Properties>
        <Filter xsi:type="ComplexFilterPart">
          <LeftOperand xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
            <Property>EventDate</Property>
            <SimpleOperator>greaterThanOrEqual</SimpleOperator>
            <DateValue>2014-11-24T21:31:59</DateValue>
          </LeftOperand>
          <LogicalOperator>AND</LogicalOperator>
          <RightOperand xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
            <Property>EventDate</Property>
            <SimpleOperator>lessThan</SimpleOperator>
            <DateValue>2014-11-24T22:31:59</DateValue>
          </RightOperand>
        </Filter>
      </RetrieveRequest>
    </RetrieveRequestMsg>
  </Body>
</Envelope>
```

**Response Information**

```
HTTP status: 200 OK
<OverallStatus>OK</OverallStatus>
<RequestID>7e4eb732-d455-4f67-9f14-54d6af116839</RequestID>
<Results xsi:type="UnsubEvent">
    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
    ... 4 valid results omitted for privacy ...
</Results>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fields I believe that are publicly exposed in the UnsubEvent:

```
<Properties>List.ID</Properties>
<Properties>List.Type</Properties>
<Properties>List.ListClassification</Properties
```

You should be able to do some basic filtering based on that.  Hope this helps!